# Get update function speed

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I'm making a game that uses the update func to move an SKSpriteNode's position.y down by 6 pixels every time it runs.

It works correctly for the first game, but then I go to the app's shop in another view controller. When I try to go back to the game after visiting the shop, it appears that the update func is running twice as fast.

Heres the code:

```
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
            roadStraight.position.y -= 6.0
}
```

Is there a way to get the firing speed of the update func so I can keep it constant? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Use the time difference between the last calling of the function as a coefficient for your movement
- Use a global speed constant which lets you easily adjust the speed of all animations without needing to search within the functions

I would do something like this (I hope you're using Swift 2.0, it's much more beautiful like this):

```
let speed = 0.01

var prev : CFTimeInterval!

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    defer { prev = currentTime }
    guard prev != nil else { return }

    let dt = currentTime - prev

    roadStraight.position.y -= speed * dt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you can see the `update:` function takes an argument of the type `CFTimeInterval`. This gives the time that elapsed from the start. Thus, you could create a property that you could use within `update:` to check the time difference each time `update:` is called. However, `update:` function is an integral part of the Sprite-kit's frame rendering so you can't simply put limits on it. Sprite-kit runs in this sequence to render every frame:
[image]

And, as you probably already know the frames-per-second or fps counter on the bottom right of the screen is far from constant. If you need to execute or run things at a constant rate your best choice is to do it out of the update: method or, if it is absolutely necessary then you could get the time difference like I described before and multiply it by a certain constant to vary the magnitude of whatever movement or positioning you are performing.